# Symbols of function in a library

Tags: shared-libraries, reverse-engineering, symbols

I know with these commands :

```
readelf -sW alloc.o | awk '$4 == "FUNC"'

nm alloc.o | awk '$2=="T" || $2=="t"'
```

I can get the names of functions wich are used in a library.

BUT, **how can I differentiate the functions which are *USED* by the library, and the functions which are *DEFINED* by the library ??**

Is there another way to get functions DEFINED by a library ?

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I know with these commands: ... I can get the names of functions which are used in a library.

No, you can't. What the commands give you is a list of functions *defined* in an object file (or a library).

> Is there another way to get functions DEFINED by a library

Why do you need another way?

> how can I differentiate the functions which are USED by the library, and the functions which are DEFINED by the library

That depends on what you mean by "USED by the library". A typical library will use some of its own functions, and some functions from outside. For example, a library containing `foo.o` and `bar.o`, where `foo()` calls `bar()`, and `bar()` calls outside `baz()`, would look like this:

```
 readelf -Ws libfoobar.a | egrep 'foo|bar|baz' | grep -v ' ABS'
File: libfoobar.a(foo.o)
     8: 0000000000000000    16 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 foo
     9: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND bar
File: libfoobar.a(bar.o)
     8: 0000000000000000    16 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 bar
     9: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND baz
```

Here you can see that `foo.o` defines `foo`, and uses `bar`; that `bar.o` defines `bar` and uses `baz` (which is not defined in this library).

What you can't see is whether `foo` is used by the library (e.g. whether `foo` is recursive or not).